# How to update a field a null value?

Tags: mysql

Tried to use these two commands but both didn't work:

```
update planes set year = 2013 where year is null;
```

and

```
update planes set year = 2013 where year = null;
```

planes - table name

Comment: `update planes set year = 2013 where year is null;` >Normally this should work. Do you get any errors?

Comment: "is null" ought to be correct. Have you checked there actually are some null fields in the table (definitely null, not just blank)? Alternatively, does it throw an error when you run the query?

Comment: What does 'didn't work' mean? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Yes, I get error code 1175: you are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without WHERE that uses KEY column

Comment: When I type:select * from planes where year is null;
I have output of 70 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unset the safe mode

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
```

and then run your Query

Comment: Worked! 
Thank you:)

Comment: Great!! Why don't you mark this as answer and let's close the topic!!